# Resume comparison bash script

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, awk, scripting

I need to create a bash script that compares resumes. There is one text file with a list of keywords, each with a point value. There are also a number of text files with resumes in them. I need to go through each resume and give each a point value based on the number of occurrences of each keyword. I'm not asking you to write the script for me, but if you were writing it, what is the general format you would use? Here's the overall plan I had:

1. Read the number of lines in the keyword file, make two arrays with that number of values in each. The first array is for the words, the second is for their values.
2. Read through each line of the keywords file, put the keywords into the first array, and each their corresponding point values into the second array.
3. Take the number of files in the resume folder, make a third and forth array with that number of values in each. (ie, if theres 5 resumes, each arrays length is 5)
4. Put the name of each resume in the third array, the forth to be used for their total score.
5. Read through each line of the first resume, when encountering a keyword add its value to the forth resume. Do this for each resume.
6. Print out the resume names in order of their point values.

Is this the general format you would follow?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something specific, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Comment: I don't want to sound sarcastic, however... Invite someone to the interview and ask for hints. People have different rules here. One should demonstrate some programming work done.

Comment: Based on those two responses, I feel I missunderstood what I was allowed to ask. That’s why I specifically said I was not asking for anyone to write any code for me, just asking how they would structure such a script, and provided my current idea of the structure. I will write the code for my idea and post that.